# Joining AND conditions with OR condition on Magento

Tags: magento, boolean

I am able to run AND and OR boolean conditions on Magento using addFieldToFilter and addAttributeToFilter.

But, I am curious about implementing more complex boolean conditions like below:

```
WHERE (`sku > 5` AND `price` > '10') OR (`name` = 'books')
```

for AND condition, I have

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter( 'sku', array('gt' => 5 )
->addFieldToFilter('price', array('gt' => 10);
```

Which translates to the first parenthesis of the WHERE condition:

```
(`sku` > 5 AND `price` > 10)
```

I do not know how to proceed from here to express the OR condition

```
`name` = 'books'
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See my earlier post:

[complex boolean conditions  on Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472713/complex-boolean-conditions-on-magento/12473013#12473013)

You can create OR by passing an array:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('price', array('gt' => 10))
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>'test%'),
        array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>'test%'),
    )
)
```

Each additional call to addAttributeToFilter() will ANDed, but firstname / lastname will be ORed.

If you need more complex select statements you can always get the select object from the collection and perform adjustments to the query. Look at Varien_Db_Select for hints :)

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(..)->orWhere(..);  // etc
```

You can even debug the query to see if it's looking ok:

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: THanks Andrew, but that one was different. I use  parenthesis to emphasize my point this time:    `WHERE (sku > 5 AND price > 10) OR (name = books)`. But  `WHERE (sku > 5) AND (price > 10 or  name = 'books')` is all I can do based on your and others' answers, which is a different one.

Comment: I saw this (and similar) answers too, but it doesn't answer this particular question. The AND expression is in parenthesis and the OR is ORing a different field. The other answers that I spotted only mentioned ORing different values for the SAME field.

Comment: Varien_Db_Select is exactly what I need. Thanks again Andrew.